# How can we count agents according to specific variables?

Tags: netlogo

We are trying to solve the following problem:

Each agent has its specific code and at each iteration the list of agents alive in that iteration is updated. We want to calculate how many agents are die of each code present in the list per iteration.
We have these procedures below (code). Obs: We need to use the profile list because of the outputs that are exported by turtle profile

Sorry for the big code below, but we tried our best to reduce it to be reproducible code

Thanks in advance

```
globals [ ListProfiles Death ]

turtles-own [ profiles-code metabolism-code reproduction-code metabolism reproduction resource-turtle ]

patches-own [ resources ]

to setup
  ca
  prepare
  ask patches [ set resources random 100 ]
  let list1 ( list 2 4 )
  let list2 ( list 5 10 )
  (
    foreach list1
  [
    this-metabolism ->

      foreach list2
      [
        this-reproduction ->
        ask n-of 1 patches
        [
          sprout 1
          [
            set metabolism this-metabolism
            set reproduction this-reproduction
            setup-turtles
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  )
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-turtles
  (
    ifelse
    metabolism = 2 [ set metabolism-code "M1" ]
    metabolism = 4 [ set metabolism-code "M2" ]
  )

  (
    ifelse
    reproduction = 5 [ set reproduction-code "R1" ]
    reproduction = 10 [ set reproduction-code "R2" ]
  )
  set profiles-code ( word metabolism-code reproduction-code )
  print ( word "profiles-code: " profiles-code )
end

to go
  ListProfilesProc
  MetaboProc
  ProbDieProc
  output

  tick
end

to ListProfilesProc
  set ListProfiles [ ]
  ask turtles [
    set ListProfiles lput profiles-code ListProfiles
  ]
  set ListProfiles remove-duplicates ListProfiles
end

to MetaboProc
  ask turtles [
    (
      ifelse
    metabolism = 2
      [
        set resource-turtle ( resources - metabolism )
        if resource-turtle <= 60 [ DieProc ]
        (
          ifelse
          reproduction = 5
          [
            if resource-turtle >= 5 [ hatch 1 ]
          ]
          reproduction = 10
          [
            if resource-turtle >= 10 [ hatch 1 ]
          ]
        )
      ]
    )
  ]
end

to DieProc
  let code profiles-code
  foreach ListProfiles [ lp ->    ;; I think, here's the problem... I can't individualize the kills by code. I've already tried several things. And therefore I can't get the output of the deaths by code. It is always repeated (general calculation)...
    
    if lp = code
    [
      set Death Death + 1
    ]
  ]
  die
end

to ProbDieProc
  ask turtles
  [
    let prob-die random-float 1.01
    if prob-die < 0.77 [ DieProc ]
  ]
end

to prepare
  carefully
    [ file-delete ( word "output.csv" ) ]
  [ ]
  file-open  ( word "output.csv" )
  file-print ( word "code_profile,death,tick" )
  file-close
end

to output
  file-open ( "output.csv" )
  foreach ListProfiles
  [
    t ->
    file-print ( word t "," Death "," ticks )
  ]
  file-close
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Deaths` as you have it is a `global` variable, which means that any time *any* turtle accesses it (either to update or read), they are all "sharing" the same value. Instead, you need to track deaths for **each** profile type. The way you have it, where `profiles-code` differentiates the different turtle types, you can tackle this a few ways- for example: you could create specific `Death` trackers for each profile type (eg. `Death-M1R1`, `Death-M1R2`... etc.) and output that as needed; or you could use a list, where you update the items in the list that correspond to a specific profile; or you could use a list of lists and use `position` to grab the death value for a different `breed`; or you could use the `tables` extension, which is the example I will show below because I think it's the cleanest and most explicit.

The `tables` extension allows what is similar to a dictionary structure if you've used that in other coding languages, where you have a {KEY: VALUE} pair such that if you enter the KEY you get out the VALUE. So the general workflow here is to build a dictionary to store the name and death count for each profile type. Then, anytime a turtle dies it will update the death count for its profile type in the dictionary.

To keep it simple, I've made only minor changes to your code above, and added comments where I made (most) updates:

```
extensions [ table ]

globals [ ListProfiles Death NInitial NFinal R Birth deaths-dict ]

turtles-own [ profiles-code metabolism-code reproduction-code metabolism reproduction resource-turtle ]

patches-own [ resources ]

to setup
  ca
  prepare
  ; Define deaths-list as a list
  set deaths-dict table:make
  ask patches [ set resources random 100 ]
  let list1 ( list 2 4 )
  let list2 ( list 5 10 )
  (
    foreach list1
  [
    this-metabolism ->

      foreach list2
      [
        this-reproduction ->
        ask n-of 1 patches
        [
          sprout 1
          [
            set metabolism this-metabolism
            set reproduction this-reproduction
            setup-turtles
            ; Add each metabolism / reproduction to the deaths dictionary with 0 as initial deaths value
            table:put deaths-dict ( word metabolism-code reproduction-code ) 0
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  )
  print deaths-dict
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-turtles
  (
    ifelse
    metabolism = 2 [ set metabolism-code "M1" ]
    metabolism = 4 [ set metabolism-code "M2" ]
  )

  (
    ifelse
    reproduction = 5 [ set reproduction-code "R1" ]
    reproduction = 10 [ set reproduction-code "R2" ]
  )
  set profiles-code ( word metabolism-code reproduction-code )
  print ( word "profiles-code: " profiles-code )
end

to go
  ; Stop the model if no turtles exist
  if not any? turtles [ stop ]
  ListProfilesProc
  MetaboProc
  ProbDieProc
  output
  tick   
end

to ListProfilesProc
  ; Simple way to get a sorted list of profile types
  set ListProfiles sort remove-duplicates [ profiles-code ] of turtles
end

to MetaboProc
  ask turtles [
    (
      ifelse
    metabolism = 2
      [
        set resource-turtle ( resources - metabolism )
        if resource-turtle <= 60 [ DieProc ]
        (
          ifelse
          reproduction = 5
          [
            if resource-turtle >= 5 [ hatch 1 ]
          ]
          reproduction = 10
          [
            if resource-turtle >= 10 [ hatch 1 ]
          ]
        )
      ]
    )
  ]
end

to ProbDieProc
  print "Running die proc..."

  ask turtles
  [
    let prob-die random-float 1
    if prob-die < 0.4 [
      DieProc
    ]
  ]
end

to DieProc
  ; Pull current death count for this profile
  let current-profile-death-count table:get deaths-dict profiles-code
  ; Increase that death count by one
  let current-profile-new-death-count current-profile-death-count + 1
  ; Update the death count in the master dictionary
  table:put deaths-dict profiles-code current-profile-new-death-count
  die
end

to prepare
  carefully
    [ file-delete ( word "output.csv" ) ]
  [ ]
  print "opening..."
  file-open  ( word "output.csv" )
  file-print ( word "code_profile,death,tick" )
  file-close
end

to output
  file-open ( "output.csv" )
  foreach ListProfiles
  [
    t ->
    let profile-deaths table:get deaths-dict t
    file-print ( word t "," profile-deaths "," ticks )
  ]
  file-close
end
```

Output then looks something like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Luke C. Helped a lot : ) :) :) : ) Thanks, thanks, thanks!